# Code for resizing treeview columns doesn't work for the second frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, resize, tk-toolkit, ttk

I need to handle resizing for my columns in the treeview which has to appear on the second page of the TK ui. But resizing works only if the treeview appears on the main page of UI, and doesn't work if the treeview is assign to the second page.

Here is the minimum code to launch the UI and see the problem. If I assign my treeview to the frame frame_tree, then resizing doesnt work.

Removing frame_tree as an argument in ttk.Treview gives me the resizing and scrolling ability that I need. But the problem is that I need my resizible treeview to work on the second page.

```
import tkinter as tk                 
from tkinter import ttk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid()
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Database",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button1.grid()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

#--------------------------------------------------
# Tree View
        frame_tree = tk.LabelFrame(self)
        frame_tree.grid()
        tree_columns = ('zero','one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen' )


        tree = ttk.Treeview(frame_tree, columns=tree_columns, show="headings", height=18)
    #####-----REMOVING --frame_tree-- from --ttk.Treeview-- in the previous line fixes the problem, but it only works on the first page then------

        tree.heading('#1', text='COLUMN 1')
        tree.heading('#2', text='COLUMN 2')
        tree.heading('#3', text='COLUMN 3')
        tree.heading('#4', text='COLUMN 4')
        tree.heading('#5', text='COLUMN 5')
        tree.heading('#6', text='COLUMN 6')
        tree.heading('#7', text='COLUMN 7')
        tree.heading('#8', text='COLUMN 8')
        tree.heading('#9', text='COLUMN 9')
        tree.heading('#10', text='COLUMN 10')
        tree.heading('#11', text='COLUMN 11')
        tree.heading('#12', text='COLUMN 12')
        tree.heading('#13', text='COLUMN 13')
        tree.heading('#14', text='COLUMN 14')
        tree.heading('#15', text='COLUMN 15')
        tree.heading('#16', text='COLUMN 16')
        tree.grid()
        tree.i = 0 

        # Handling Resize
        controller.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        controller.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code related to column resizing. However, I'm guessing what you're really asking is about the treeview widget filling the whole frame.

If that's the case, you need to give a positive weight to the row and column that the treeview is in:

```
frame_tree.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_tree.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Since you are putting frame_tree into `self` with `grid`, you need to do the same for the master of `frame_tree` as well:

```
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

For widgets that contain only a single widget (eg: `tree` inside of `frame_tree` and `frame_tree` inside of `self`, `pack` is arguably a better choice over grid since it only requires a single line:

```
frame_tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```